# JAXB : Read non-static attributes into a collection

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb

I would like to write a JAXB implementation to read/unmarshall the below XML. Challenge here is how to read the attributes whose names are not defined. In the below example, the keys can vary from A1 to AN. My question is, can we use JAXB here? If yes, how to write Node.java class?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<Node A1="blabla" 
    A2="xyz" 
    A3="APPLICATION" 
    A4="dfd" 
    A5="dfd" 
    ...
    >       
</Node>


public class Node {
//What is to be done here? 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @XmlAnyAttribute :

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Node {

    @XmlAnyAttribute
    private Map<QName,String> attributeMap;

    //getters and setters

}
```

Source : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyAttribute.html